# PHP path - including a file from the same directory

Tags: php, include

I have a problem with my path. Say I have a PHP file in `/home/bla/www/dev/source/test.php`. In this `test.php` file I want to include a file in

```
/home/bla/www/config/conf.php

<?php
    include_once("");
?>
```

I don't want to include it like `include` `/home/bla/www/config/conf.php`. How can I do it?

PS: This fails:

```
include_once("../../config/conf.php");
```

Comment: Which error message do you get when the include fails? A permission error?

Comment: Not persmission but a include errs like "no such file found on bla bla"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use an absolute path instead of a relative:

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/conf.php");
```

This would work from any folder.

Comment: Note that this won't work if the script is run on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

```
$current_dir = dirname(__FILE__);
require_once($current_dir.'/../foo/bar.php');
```

Note that require_once('foo.php') looks for foo.php in the same directory as the script, but require_once('../foo.php') is not relative to the path of the script, but relative to the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

As DaDaDom suggests, permissions may well be the problem here. Have you tried addressing the file using an absolute path (`/home/bla/www/config/conf.php`), and if it fails, what's the error?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer